# Is a^n b^k , 0 <= n <= k^2, a context-free language?

Tags: regular-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

I don't think it's a CFL, but I'm having a hard time using the pumping lemma to prove this. Is there any way I can use homomorphism? Maybe h(a)= a, h(b) = lambda...
If the pumping lemma is more appropriate then maybe...
let m = constant of pumping lemma for some string w = a^nb^k
let w =xyz such that |xy|<=m and |y|>=1
let y =a^i for some i<=k^2
then I'm completely lost...
It would be greatly appreciated if someone could kindly help me with this one.

Comment: should i be pumping up or down? I tried down but cant get anything that makes sense

Comment: It seems you are using the pumping lemma for regular languages, not for context-free languages.